# Neo4j not performing for undirected relationship

Tags: neo4j

I've been working with neo4j 4.1 for a while now and whilst I feel that the graph structure should be a good fit for my problem, I can't get it to perform in any reasonable time.

I'll detail the model and problem below, but I'm wondering whether (a) graphs are just not a good fit or (b) I've modelled the problem incorrectly.

In my domain, I have two labels: `Person` and `Skill`. Each as an `id` attribute and there is an index on this attribute.

Skills are related to one another in a parent-child relationship, implying that one or more child skills belong to the parent skill, as follows:

`(s:Skill)-[r:IS_IN_CAT]->(s2:Skill)`

A Person is related to a Skill as follows:

`(p:Person)-[r:HAS_SKILL]->(s:Skill)`

This is illustrated as below:

[image]

The question I want to ask is, given a Person who has a skill, find me all paths to all other people via that skill.

In the diagram above, if Person A was the person, I'd expect 2 paths:

`(Person A) - [HAS_SKILL] - (Skill 1-1-1) - [IS_IN_CAT] - (Skill 1-1) - [IS_IN_CAT] - (Skill 1-1-2)  - [HAS_SKILL] - (Person B)`

And

`(Person A) - [HAS_SKILL] - (Skill 1-1-1) - [IS_IN_CAT] - (Skill 1-1) - [IS_IN_CAT] - (Skill 1)  - [IS_IN_CAT] - (Skill 1-2) - [HAS_SKILL] - (Person C)`

The way I'm asking this query is as follows.

`MATCH (p:Person {id: 100}) - [h:HAS_SKILL] -> (s:Skill) - [r:IS_IN_CAT*..] - (s2:Skill) <- [h2:HAS_SKILL] - (p2:Person)`

For any moderately sized graph (10,000 skills, 1000 people, 5 skills per person) this doesn't ever return.

I'm fairly sure it's the undirected nature of the `[r:IS_IN_CAT*..]` part of the query but I don't see how to re-model to make this perform any better.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved this by changing my query to rely on directed relationships only. This brought the performance down to sub-second for very large data sets.

The query ended up looking like:

```
MATCH (p:Person {id: 100}) - [h:HAS_SKILL] -> (s:Skill) - [r:IS_IN_CAT*..] -> (parentSkill:Skill) <- [r:IS_IN_CAT*..] - (s2:Skill) <- [h2:HAS_SKILL] - (p2:Person)
```

The introduction of the `parentSkill` allowed the relationships to stay directional.